# DataTables column titles all crammed over 1st column

Tags: css, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to get a simple DataTable grid to render, but I'm getting an odd behavior. The column headers all look crammed over the 1st column.

I know it is because of some styling being applied to the class `workspace-table` because when I delete all styles related to that class the problem goes away. (I inhierited the styles, and am not very css literate).

Could someone tell me which style is breaking this? I have tried removing individual classes or styles but I'm not seeing what the issue is.

[fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/EX8LZ/17/)

**styles**:

```
.workspace-table{
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.workspace-table .column-resize-icon{
  float: right;
  color: gray;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.workspace-table .table-desc-width{
  width: 288px !important;
}
.workspace-table .table-dollar-format{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.workspace-table thead/*.headerText*/{
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: left !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.workspace-table tr {
    border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
}
.workspace-table th {
  border-right: 2px solid;
  background: #969696;
}
.workspace-table th .fa-sort{
  color: grey;
}
.workspace-table th .fa-sort-up{
  color: white;
}
.workspace-table th .fa-sort-down{
  color: white;
}
.workspace-table .border-right .fa{
  display: table-cell !important;
}
.workspace-table .border-right{
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.workspace-table > thead > tr > th, .workspace-table > tbody > tr > th, 
.workspace-table > tfoot > tr > th, .workspace-table > thead > tr > td, 
.workspace-table > tbody > tr > td, .workspace-table > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.workspace-table .negative {
  color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed display:inliine and float:left from .workspace-table thead.

It looks like someone commented out part of that CSS selector, which maybe wasn't intended for  the thead element itself, but maybe one of it's children?

http://jsfiddle.net/S9QXY/

```
.workspace-table thead/*.headerText*/{
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: left !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

float kills any display.

Do not float your table elements and it will render fine.
jsfiddle.net/EX8LZ/18/

as said , do not either modify display values, unless you have good reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Take out the display: inline and the float:left from your thead rule:

```
    .workspace-table thead/*.headerText*/{
      color: white;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      padding-right: 5px;
      text-align: left !important;
      text-decoration: underline;
}
```